What does "У богатых свои причуды" mean?
I don't quite get what this phrase means. What is the idea behind it and when/where is it used.

Translations to languages other than Russian are off topic here. You might try your luck on English SE and/or Spanish SE. I've updated your question so that it stays on topic.

"The rich have their whims" or "The rich have their caprices", where "have" bears, in this context, a slight connotation of "are entitled to" or "can afford".
